# Cygwin SSHD resets connection only if called locally

Tags: ssh, router, cygwin, sshd

I have a WinXP box (called PETER) with Cygwin installed.  This is its version:

```
C:\bin> uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-5.1 peter 1.7.24(0.269/5/3) 2013-08-15 11:55 i686 Cygwin
```

I have installed SSHD on it for years and everything worked well. Recently I have changed the router from Speedport 722V to Speedport 921V (I needed IPv6). I have properly set port forwarding rules and they seem to work.

Now I have this strange effect:

- users from the Internet can connect;
- I can connect via SSH to my Uni, from there connect to PETER;
- I can connect to PETER to its local IP address 192.168.2.107;
- **but I can not connect to it** by using the public IP address (which is delivered by dyndns.com) or the DNS name.

I have checked that the IP address is correct. It doesn't work for both the DNS name and the numerical IPv4 address. Port forwarding works: Internet users can connect and as the log file shows, I can connect, but my connection is *reset*, i.e. actively terminated.

This is the SSH output when I try it:

```
C:\> ssh -vvvv 79.223.25.218
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 61: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 79.223.25.218 [79.223.25.218] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/cygdrive/c/text/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/text/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/text/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

I only get this eventvwr output: `... sshd: PID 720: Comparing 79.223.25.218 to 79.223.25.218 (p4FDF19DA.dip0.t-ipconnect.de:p4FDF19DA.dip0.t-ipconnect.de).`

This is my sshd_config:

```
Port 22
AddressFamily inet
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

# The default requires explicit activation of protocol 1
#Protocol 2

# HostKey for protocol version 1
#HostKey /etc/ssh_host_key
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
#HostKey /etc/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh_host_dsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh_host_ecdsa_key

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
#KeyRegenerationInterval 1h
#ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
# obsoletes QuietMode and FascistLogging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes no
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#RSAAuthentication yes
#PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
#RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# RhostsRSAAuthentication and HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing, 
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will 
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
#UsePAM no

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#X11Forwarding no
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
Compression yes

# after 3*2min of no answer from the client, terminate the connection
# so after a hibernation etc. the connection will most likely be dead.
ClientAliveInterval 2m
ClientAliveCountMax 3

#UseDNS yes
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/sbin/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

To make things more obscure, I "fixed" this problem the other day by modifying the `/etc/hosts.allow` file, but this "fix" doesn't work any more. It was not needed anyhow for the last years, so I'm all the more confused. The other day I was under the impression that the router might reverse-resolve the IP number to a name, something the old router maybe did differently than the new one??

Does anyone have any idea? I'm clueless, but I don't really understand all of the workings (e.g. the `/etc/hosts.allow` and `.deny` files are new to me).

**More info:** It doesn't work even with empty `hosts.allow`and `.deny`files. SSHD DEBUG3 logging doesn't show any reason for disconnect. Right now, I think it's a hardware problem with the router...

Comment: Did you set up the same port forwarding in the new router? Do other services work fine?

Comment: There are no other services, but I can connect from the outside, so port forwarding must be working OK.

Comment: Do I get your setup right: `PETER - SPEEDPORT - INTERNET - UNI`? Where do ,,users from the internet'' can connect to -- to the cygwin `sshd`? You ssh'd into `UNI` only for testing purposes, to check if you can connect to `PETER` from the ,,outside''?!

Comment: "Users from the Internet" is anyone connected to the Internet and to check that, I connect to Uni and test from there. The "normal" user would just connect from his workplace on the Internet (no Uni).

Comment: have you figured out why?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the reset of the TCP connection was an "improvement" in my new router. What I'm trying to do is called "NAT loopback", [see WP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback), and the manufacturers of my router seem to share the (in my understanding faulty) opinion that NAT loopback is a security issue. I don't see how it could be, but there it is: my router actively prohibits such connections.

My solution is a hack, where I have a script run before using SSH. Said script checks if I'm in the office and if so, replaces the DNS address of my server with its local address. Stupid, but I see no other way.